# JSON NSDictionary request

Tags: ios, objective-c, json

I have an return value from JSON which looks like this

```
operator: [
       {
        id: "AS",
        voucher: [
               {
                id: "1858",
                hargajual: "10550"
               }
                ]
       },
       {
        id: "IM3",
        voucher: [
               {
               id: "1859",
               hargajual: "26000"
               }
                ]
       }
]
```

I try to get the list of NSArray for the id by using the

```
NSArray *idArray = [dataDictionary valueForKeyPath:@"operator.voucher.id"];
```

However the result that came out when i NSLog my array was ( (1858), (1859) ) not  (1858 , 1859).

Thank you for your help and sorry if my english is not good.

:D

Comment: can you give us the real json, as this snippet isn't valid.

Comment: That's because you've got arrays two deep in the JSON.  You get an NSArray for each JSON array.  Go to json.org and learn the JSON syntax.

Comment: And, probably because you don't understand the JSON syntax, you left out the initial `{` and final `}` in your listing above.

Answer (score 0):

That is the result you should get, b/c each `voucher` is an array, and thus could have multiple `id`s.  If you need a different format, you'll have to do it yourself from this data.